# How do I secure this post request to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, security, csrf

I'm trying to work out security for my AJAX calls. I've got a jQuery post call which deletes a note. From what I've read, it seems that I need to use `protect_from_forgery` to ensure that the post is coming from a valid user.

This is what I have so far

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
...
```

index.html

```
$.post('../delete_note',{id:$('#note_id').val()}, function(data) {

});
```

note_controller.rb

```
def delete_note
    y params
    render :text => "success"
end
```

At the moment, the post request gets run by Rails, even though I'm not sending any security token with it. What do I need to do secure the call?

I'm using Rails 3.0.1 and [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for user management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to ensure the user is signed in, using in your note controller something like:

```
before_filter :authenticate_member!, :except => [:index]
```

Additionally, check if the user has the rights to delete the note, for that you want to use a authorization solution like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can the user be authenticated if I'm not sending anything with the post request? Does Rails only have the data that is sent with the request?

Comment: If you are using devise, the authentication is stored in session.